# Best way to display thesis committee member names along with university affiliation

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to make a "movie credits-style" list (*not* animated/scrolling) of my thesis committee for a "front matter" page in my thesis.

Below is a mock-up I made with a word processor.

[image: mockup]

That is the basic idea I had in mind.

Here is a very basic MWE (with no formatting) containing some of the crucial packages that I am using for my thesis.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Thesis Committee}

\noindent
Firstname Lastname, Ph.D.\\
\emph{advisor}\\
Department of Something,\\
Something University\\

\noindent
Firstname Longlastname, Ph.D.\\
\emph{chair}\\
Department of Something,\\
Something University\\

\noindent
Firstname Lastname, Ph.D.\\
Department of Longsomething,\\
Longsomething University\\

\noindent
Firstname Lastname, Ph.D.\\
Department of Longsomething,\\
Longsomething University\\

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

What is the best way to obtain the "movie credits-style" list shown in the image at the top of this page?

One possibility would be to create a `tabular` with three columns and multiple rows.  But I would like to be able to have the "credits" be centered on the overall page -- and perhaps adjust the horizontal alignment/centering later in order to make it look nice with the heading.  What is the best way to do this, either with or without `tabular`?

Comment: Regarding your wish for "centered"  alignment: Do you refer to horizontally or vertically centered and what exactly is wrong about using a `tabular`?

Comment: Something along the lines of `{\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Firstname Lastname, Ph.D. & Department of Something,\\
\emph{advisor}  & Something University\\ \addlinespace

Firstname Longlastname, Ph.D. & Department of Something,\\
\emph{chair}  & Something University\\  \addlinespace

Firstname Lastname, Ph.D. & Department of Longsomething,\\
& Longsomething University\\  \addlinespace

Firstname Lastname, Ph.D. & Department of Longsomething,\\
& Longsomething University\\  \addlinespace
\end{tabular}
}` should work fine.

Comment: @leandriis I would like it horizontally centered, but I may want to adjust the centering, such that the tabular is not actually centered, but visually looks centered.

Comment: You can always replace the `\centering` with `\hspace{<width>}` and a width of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use a text TABstack.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackText
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Thesis Committee}

\setstacktabulargap{30pt}
\centerline{\tabularCenterstack{rl}{
Firstname Lastname, Ph.D.&
Department of Something,\\
\emph{advisor}&
Something University\\
&\\
Firstname Longlastname, Ph.D.&
Department of Something,\\
\emph{chair}&
Something University\\
&\\
Firstname Lastname, Ph.D.&
Department of Longsomething,\\
& Longsomething University\\
&\\
Firstname Lastname, Ph.D.&
Department of Longsomething,\\
& Longsomething University}}

\end{document}
```

[image]